# "find: missing argument to `-exec'" running in a Java process builder

Tags: groovy, jenkins, find, processbuilder

I am trying to run the find command inside Jenkins (https://jenkins-ci.org) script console, which allows running groovy scripts from a web interface.

My code is:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder();
pb.directory(new File("/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/myJob");
pb.redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
pb.redirectError(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
command = 'find . -name build.xml -exec echo \"{}\" \\;'
println(command)
pb.command(command.split(" "));
pb.start().waitFor();
```

The web UI will display the result of println:

```
find . -name build.xml -exec echo "{}" \;
```

While the jenkins log (/var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log) logs the following error:

```
find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

However, if I run that same command outputted in the web UI (`find . -name build.xml -exec echo "{}" \;`) through a shell I get no such error.

In addition, if I replace the `\;` witih `+`, the command works!

So something is fishy with processBuilder and the `\\;` being passed as a command line argument

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem for the error with `\;` is that you are mixing shell escaping/quoting with the plain passing of params of the exec functions.

Drop the `\` before the `;` and it works.  `;` needs `\` *only* in the shell, since it is used to separate commands there.  Same goes for quoting `{}` - when passing params to the `exec*`-style functions, no shell-style quoting/escaping is needed, since no shell interprets it (unless of course you run `sh -c`):

```
def command = 'find . -name build.xml -exec echo {} ;' // XXX
new ProcessBuilder()
    .directory(new File("/tmp"))
    .inheritIO()
    .command(command.split(" ")) // everything is just a list of strings
    .start()
```

And this is basically the same thing in groovy:

```
("/tmp" as File).eachFileRecurse{
    if (it.name=="build.xml") {
        println it
    }
}
```

Comment: it always better to use `List` as an argument to command. I mean with doing any splits - especially if runtime arguments might be passed. However +1.

Comment: yes i dislike the split too.  it only works here, because there are no whitespaces in the arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you replace all of the above with:

```
String output = ['bash', '-c', 'find . -name "*.xml" -exec echo "{}" \\;']
    .execute(null, new File('/tmp')).text
```

Comment: why bother with the bash?  `['find', '/tmp', '-name', '*.xml', '-exec', 'echo', '{}', ';'].execute().text`.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! That is an acceptable replacement for what I want to do. Your answer also led me to learn more groovy to do what I really wanted to do with a command line: find files and replace with sed, but groovy provides excellent IO apis: http://groovy-lang.org/groovy-dev-kit.html#_working_with_io  

*Still*, I'd like to know why ProcessBuilder is failing to pass the `\;`, I can't come up with a reason for it failing